# Was the woman who visited Angela Eragon's mother?

Tags: christopher-paolini, inheritance-cycle

In *Eragon*, a woman was able to talk to Solembum, the werecat. I remember there being a suspicion that it might have been Eragon's mother, but I don't remember if the fact was confirmed either in later books or other words.

Comment: Don't really remember it now. But I think the woman's name was same as Eragon's mother.

Comment: Yes, that is the case, confirmed by my reading another 3 pages beyond asking this question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is some considerable evidence that it is indeed his mother. First of all:

1. The woman's name is Selena, which is the same as Eragon's mother.
2. The timing seems to be coincident with Selena's visit to give birth to Eragon, from the vague time references made.
3. The woman was extremely sorry. No doubt Eragon's mother would be in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

### While there is some evidence that she is, Christopher Paolini will stay not say so outright.

When asked *this very question* in [his recent Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/4i0tf1/hey_reddit_im_fantasy_author_christopher/d389eqe), Christopher Paolini skirted the question, possibly implying that there might be more to the story.

> **Was the woman Angela talks about in Eragon as having been able to talk to Solembum Eragon's mother?**
>   Could have been.
>   <sub>([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/4i0tf1/hey_reddit_im_fantasy_author_christopher/d389eqe))</sub>